# Bare Metal Raspberry Pi Framebuffer not working

Tags: rust, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, framebuffer, bare-metal

I have been working on writing a bare metal program for a raspberry pi 3B 1.2

I have written a start function in assembler which is able to call a rust function. I am currently trying to initialize and draw a single color to the frame buffer. When I try this and run in on my pi, the default gradient stops showing and the screen goes black. However, nothing else shows. Is there a reason why this is the case?

Here is my start function:

```rust
    pub extern "C" fn start() {
    let fb = gpu::init();
    
    if let Ok(fbi) = fb {
        fbi.draw();
    }
}
```

Here is my `gpu.rs` file:

```rust
//! This module provides an interface to the raspberry pi's built in gpu

use super::mmio;

const MBOX_BASE_OFFSET: usize = 0x0000b880;

pub fn init() -> Result<FBInfo, ()>{
    let fb_info = FBInfo {
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080,
        v_width: 1920,
        v_height: 1080,
        pitch: 0,
        bit_depth: 16,
        x_offset: 0,
        y_offset: 0,
        ptr: 0,
        size: 0,
    };

    let gpu_channel = Channel::new(0).unwrap();

    unsafe {
        let fbi_ptr = &fb_info as *const FBInfo;
        gpu_channel.write(fbi_ptr as u32 + 0x40000000)
    }

    if gpu_channel.read() == 0 {Ok(fb_info)} else {Err(())}
}

fn wait_util_ready() {
    loop {
        //wait until mailbox is ready
        let status = MailboxRegister::Status.read();
        if status & 0x80000000 == 0 {
            break;
        }
    }
}

pub struct Channel{
    number: u32,
}

impl Channel {
    const CHANNELS: u32 = 7;

    pub fn new(number: u32) -> Result<Self, ()> {
        if number < Channel::CHANNELS {Ok(Channel { number: number} )} else { Err(()) }
    }

    pub fn read(&self) -> u32 {
        loop {
            wait_util_ready();

            let value = mmio::read_at_offset(MBOX_BASE_OFFSET + MailboxRegister::Read as usize);

            if value & 0b1111 == self.number {
                return value;
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn write(&self, value: u32) {
        wait_util_ready();

        mmio::write_at_offset(value + self.number, MBOX_BASE_OFFSET + MailboxRegister::Write as usize)
    }
}

pub enum MailboxRegister {
    Read = 0,
    Poll= 16,
    Sender = 20,
    Status = 24,
    Configuration = 28,
    Write = 32
}

impl MailboxRegister {
    pub fn read(self) -> u32 {
        mmio::read_at_offset(MBOX_BASE_OFFSET + self as usize)
    }
}

#[repr(align(4))]
pub struct FBInfo {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
    v_width: u32,
    v_height: u32,
    pitch: u32,
    bit_depth: u32,
    x_offset: u32,
    y_offset: u32,
    ptr: u32,
    size: u32,
}

impl FBInfo {
    pub fn draw(&self) {
        let color: u16 = 0xff;
        loop {
            let mut current_pxl = self.ptr;
            for y in 0..self.v_height {
                for x in 0..self.v_width {
                    unsafe {
                        core::ptr::write_volatile((current_pxl as *mut u16), color);
                    }
                    current_pxl += 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my `mmio.rs` file:

```rust
    pub const MMIO_START: usize = 0x3F000000;

    pub fn write_at_offset(data: u32, offset: usize) {
        unsafe {
            core::ptr::write_volatile((MMIO_START + offset) as *mut u32, data);
        }
    }

    pub fn read_at_offset(offset: usize) -> u32 {
        unsafe {
            core::ptr::read_volatile((MMIO_START + offset) as *const u32)
        }
    }
```

Any help would be apprecaited.

Edit: Here is the disassembly of the compiled program:

```
Disassembly of section .rodata.cst16:

0000000000000000 <.rodata.cst16>:
   0:   00000780        udf     #1920
   4:   00000438        udf     #1080
   8:   00000780        udf     #1920
   c:   00000438        udf     #1080

Disassembly of section .rodata.cst8:

0000000000000010 <.rodata.cst8>:
  10:   00000000        udf     #0
  14:   00000010        udf     #16

Disassembly of section .text.boot:

0000000000000018 <_start>:
  18:   d53800a0        mrs     x0, mpidr_el1
  1c:   92401c00        and     x0, x0, #0xff
  20:   b4000040        cbz     x0, 28 <master>
  24:   1400000b        b       50 <hang>

0000000000000028 <master>:
  28:   58000180        ldr     x0, 58 <hang+0x8>
  2c:   580001a1        ldr     x1, 60 <hang+0x10>
  30:   14000001        b       34 <bss_init>

0000000000000034 <bss_init>:
  34:   eb01001f        cmp     x0, x1
  38:   54000060        b.eq    44 <enter_rust>  // b.none
  3c:   f900001f        str     xzr, [x0]
  40:   91002000        add     x0, x0, #0x8

0000000000000044 <enter_rust>:
  44:   5800013e        ldr     x30, 68 <hang+0x18>
  48:   910003df        mov     sp, x30
  4c:   94001020        bl      40cc <start>

0000000000000050 <hang>:
  50:   14000000        b       50 <hang>
  54:   d503201f        nop
  58:   00000070        udf     #112
  5c:   00000000        udf     #0
  60:   00000070        udf     #112
  64:   00000000        udf     #0
  68:   00004070        udf     #16496
  6c:   00000000        udf     #0

Disassembly of section .text._ZN8graph_os8platform6raspi33gpu6FBInfo4draw17h1a3de04fef86caf4E:

0000000000004070 <_ZN8graph_os8platform6raspi33gpu6FBInfo4draw17h1a3de04fef86caf4E>:
    4070:       b9400c09        ldr     w9, [x0, #12]
    4074:       34000069        cbz     w9, 4080 <_ZN8graph_os8platform6raspi33gpu6FBInfo4draw17h1a3de04fef86caf4E+0x10>
    4078:       52801fe8        mov     w8, #0xff                       // #255
    407c:       14000003        b       4088 <_ZN8graph_os8platform6raspi33gpu6FBInfo4draw17h1a3de04fef86caf4E+0x18>
    4080:       14000000        b       4080 <_ZN8graph_os8platform6raspi33gpu6FBInfo4draw17h1a3de04fef86caf4E+0x10>
    4084:       b9400c09        ldr     w9, [x0, #12]
    4088:       b940080b        ldr     w11, [x0, #8]
    408c:       34ffffe9        cbz     w9, 4088 <_ZN8graph_os8platform6raspi33gpu6FBInfo4draw17h1a3de04fef86caf4E+0x18>
    4090:       34ffffeb        cbz     w11, 408c <_ZN8graph_os8platform6raspi33gpu6FBInfo4draw17h1a3de04fef86caf4E+0x1c>
    4094:       b940200a        ldr     w10, [x0, #32]
    4098:       2a1f03ec        mov     w12, wzr
    409c:       340000cb        cbz     w11, 40b4 <_ZN8graph_os8platform6raspi33gpu6FBInfo4draw17h1a3de04fef86caf4E+0x44>
    40a0:       2a0a03ed        mov     w13, w10
    40a4:       7100056b        subs    w11, w11, #0x1
    40a8:       1100094a        add     w10, w10, #0x2
    40ac:       790001a8        strh    w8, [x13]
    40b0:       54ffff81        b.ne    40a0 <_ZN8graph_os8platform6raspi33gpu6FBInfo4draw17h1a3de04fef86caf4E+0x30>  // b.any
    40b4:       1100058c        add     w12, w12, #0x1
    40b8:       6b09019f        cmp     w12, w9
    40bc:       54fffe40        b.eq    4084 <_ZN8graph_os8platform6raspi33gpu6FBInfo4draw17h1a3de04fef86caf4E+0x14>  // b.none
    40c0:       b940080b        ldr     w11, [x0, #8]
    40c4:       35fffeeb        cbnz    w11, 40a0 <_ZN8graph_os8platform6raspi33gpu6FBInfo4draw17h1a3de04fef86caf4E+0x30>
    40c8:       17fffffb        b       40b4 <_ZN8graph_os8platform6raspi33gpu6FBInfo4draw17h1a3de04fef86caf4E+0x44>

Disassembly of section .text.start:

00000000000040cc <start>:
    40cc:       d10183ff        sub     sp, sp, #0x60
    40d0:       90ffffe8        adrp    x8, 0 <_start-0x18>
    40d4:       90ffffe9        adrp    x9, 0 <_start-0x18>
    40d8:       3dc00100        ldr     q0, [x8]
    40dc:       fd400921        ldr     d1, [x9, #16]
    40e0:       52971308        mov     w8, #0xb898                     // #47256
    40e4:       72a7e008        movk    w8, #0x3f00, lsl #16
    40e8:       3d800fe0        str     q0, [sp, #48]
    40ec:       fd0023e1        str     d1, [sp, #64]
    40f0:       a904ffff        stp     xzr, xzr, [sp, #72]
    40f4:       b9400109        ldr     w9, [x8]
    40f8:       37ffffe9        tbnz    w9, #31, 40f4 <start+0x28>
    40fc:       9100c3e9        add     x9, sp, #0x30
    4100:       52a8000a        mov     w10, #0x40000000                // #1073741824
    4104:       0b0a0129        add     w9, w9, w10
    4108:       b9000909        str     w9, [x8, #8]
    410c:       b9400109        ldr     w9, [x8]
    4110:       37ffffe9        tbnz    w9, #31, 410c <start+0x40>
    4114:       b85e8109        ldur    w9, [x8, #-24]
    4118:       72000d3f        tst     w9, #0xf
    411c:       54ffff81        b.ne    410c <start+0x40>  // b.any
    4120:       34000069        cbz     w9, 412c <start+0x60>
    4124:       910183ff        add     sp, sp, #0x60
    4128:       d65f03c0        ret
    412c:       ad4187e0        ldp     q0, q1, [sp, #48]
    4130:       f9402be8        ldr     x8, [sp, #80]
    4134:       9100c3e0        add     x0, sp, #0x30
    4138:       ad0007e0        stp     q0, q1, [sp]
    413c:       f90013e8        str     x8, [sp, #32]
    4140:       ad0187e0        stp     q0, q1, [sp, #48]
    4144:       f9002be8        str     x8, [sp, #80]
    4148:       97ffffca        bl      4070 <_ZN8graph_os8platform6raspi33gpu6FBInfo4draw17h1a3de04fef86caf4E>
    414c:       d4200020        brk     #0x1
```

Comment: have you done the same in C and had it work?  have you examined the disassembly to confirm it is doing what you think

Comment: @old_timer I haven't tried this in C, but I used the baking pi course as a guide. I added the disassembly to the post.

Comment: the baking pi course is broken.  you need to try one experiment at a time.  rust is an experiment.  were you successful in assembly language with the pi course?

Comment: and maybe try something simpler than video.  Have you been successful with other things using rust baremetal for this platform before trying the mailboxes?

Comment: @old_timer Thanks for the advice. In what way is the course broken? Also, is there a simpler goal that I could observe before trying video?

Comment: If you look at the baremetal forum on the pi website you will see that there are countless people dealing with mostly build issues with the baking pi examples.   I would try blinking the led first if it is not one of the pi's that the led was painful, I would blink an led first anyway, using an external led or voltmeter off if a gpio pin if the on board led was one of the painful ones. (most were not).

Comment: Is your problem 1) the startup 2) rust 3) not rust but just generally not talking to the chip/gpu mailbox correctly?   what have you done to divide the problem in half, and in half and in half to figure out what category the problem lies?

Comment: @old_timer I just tried to turn on an LED using assembler as a baby step and it worked. Thanks

Comment: yeah so now it is a matter of doing the same with rust.  It is on my list of things to do is get to know bare metal rust, but have not done that yet...good luck...there seem to be some good examples out there.